# Need mythical creatures for high fantasy

Tags: fantasy

I want my novel to have more than just the real common mythical creatures. (Like dragons) Are there any websites or books with mythical creatures in them? I'd prefer they had pictures or at least a detailed description of what the creature would look like. At the moment I'm need more benevolent nature spirits like nymphs or dryads.

Comment: you can literally search for "encyclopedia of mythical creatures" on Amazon and come up with a page and a half of results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about writing. It might be on topic on Worldbuilding; I've flagged it for the mods to take a look.

Comment: That being said, go to Wikipedia, and look up 'List of Legendary Creatures by Type'. If you can't get ideas from that, nothing will help you.

Comment: GURPS sourcebooks? D&D Monster manual? Ancient Aliens?

Comment: I'd say this won't be on topic on Worldbuilding. Worldbuilding is for help with specific aspects of an imaginary world; not only is this asking for a kitchen sink list of imaginary creatures (which would itself be well enough off topic) but it's asking for books or web sites listing such creatures.

Answer (score 2):

Try this... it may help? It has lots of links that provide details on mythical creatures.

http://www.mythicalcreaturesguide.com/m/page/List+of+Mythical+Creatures

Answer (score 0):

I really like this site because it is multicultural: http://mythology.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page